# Java object declaration

Tags: java, object

Hey guys I am learning java and I am confused on object declaration when there is a subclass.
if the line reads: Superclass a = new Subclass();
would the object a be type superclass or subclass? and would you be able to use methods in both the superclass and subclass class?

Comment: Try it!  Does it compile?

Comment: You can check all this by simple demo implementation. For finding the type of object a you can use instanceOf operator to find class type. Check [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/referencing-subclass-objects-subclass-vs-superclass-reference/) external link.

Comment: That is "instanceof". To answer, a is of type Subclass.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of it as creating an object of Subclass but attaching to it a label (i.e. type) of SuperClass. The compiler looks at this label and sees SuperClass , hence only fields and methods of SuperClass are available, although it is in fact an object of SubClass.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to use the superclass methods only. See here for dressing details: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_inheritance.asp

Answer (score 0):

1. Object will be of type SubClass
2. You cannot simply use methods of SubClass because java compiler thinks the object is Superclass  and would not allow you to code invocation of SubClass methods. To do so, you need casting like this:

   `((SubClass)a).subClassMethod()`

Answer (score 0):

In java if you pass subclass reference to superclass object then you will only be able to access the method and variable in superclass.

- let's say your subclass has one method print(), but your superclass does not then you will not be able to access that subclass method
- also if your subclass override superclass method then it will class subclass method when you call them

Answer (score 0):

When a variable is declared it's type is defined with it. Its assignment does not affect its type. Its type is how it can be used and only how it can be used. Sub-classes of this type may have additional features but when the type is not that subclass, these features are not accessible because as far as any receiving function is concerned it uses the type as the way to determine what functions are available.

Consider the following code snippets:

```
public class SuperClass {
    ...
    public void normalFunction(){...}
    ...
}
```

//

```
public class SubClassA extends SuperClass {
    ...
    public void specialFunctionA(){...}
    ...
}
```

//

```
public class SubClassB extends SuperClass {
    ...
    public void specialFunctionB(){...}
    ...
}
```

//

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SubClassA a = new SubClassA();
        a.specialFunctionA(); //it's ok here because here its TYPE is SubClassA
        a.normalFunction(); //also fine because superclass functions are inherited
        someFunction(a);
    }

    public void someFunction(SuperClass sc){
        sc.specialFunctionA(); // How could we know whether specialFunctionA is available?
        sc.specialFunctionB(); // How could we know whether specialFunctionB is available?
        sc.normalFunction(); // fine because this function is declare in SuperClass
    }
}
```